# вывод объектов в textarea через запятую

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть массив с объектами внутри. Мне нужно определенное значение объекта вынести в texarea через запятую с текстом перед перечнем. Делю как-то так:

```
 var arr = {};
        $("textarea").append("Result: ");
            for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        $("textarea").append(arr[i].car + ", ");
            }
```

В общем-то все отображается как нужно, только вот смущает запятая в конце. Да и сам способ выдачи может ли быть иначе записан? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), в вашем случае еще метод [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var arr = [];
$("textarea").append("Result: ");
$("textarea").append(arr.map(function (x) { return x.car }).join(', '));
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что было нужно!